# How to capture **Video and Photo** at same time in an activity

Tags: android, video-capture, android-camera, image-capture, recorder

I want to take **video and photo at same time**.

I have **two buttons**.

1. When user click on one it have to take video and
2. Another button then it have to stop recording video and take photo.

Now I am trying recorder and camera but its not working fine ,

Also note **not both in same time i want to do one after another** vice versa ..

What is a good idea for this?

Comment: You can never start both the MediaRecorder and Camera simultaneously untill and unless ur device has multi-cam support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think it's possible. Camera and recorder will not work together because they both block camera and don't allow other apps' recorders and cameras (and each other) to use camera at the same time.

Comment: Of course, your device may have 2 and more cameras, and they can work at the same time, but it isn't what you need.

Comment: i have edited my question . i want to do one after another. if user click video it have have video and if user click on photo if must stop recording and have to take photo.

Comment: @Ganapathy It's possible. Look at [android.hardware.Camera documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).Note that you still unable to switch between photo and video modes momentally: the screen will flick, camera will change the focus, and the switch will take some time.

Answer (score 6):

If your recording video then, you could when the button is pressed, calculate the frame of the video that corresponds to the time the button was pressed then just pull that frame out of the video file and use that as your image. I've never done it on android, but it should be possible.

EDIT: have a look at the previewcallback() in camera:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html